# Changing content of a matrix in c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, matrix

How do you change just part of a matrix in c (I'm actually in Objective-C, but using matrices in c). For example:

```
NSInteger tempMapMatrix[100][100] =
   {{0,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,2,4,4,4,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,4,3,4,4,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,2,3,3,2,1,4,1,3,3,4,4,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,3,3,3,2,4,1,1,1,4,4,4,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,4,4,0},
    {0,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,0,2,3,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0},
    {4,4,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4},
    {0,4,1,2,2,2,1,1,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,4,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,4,4,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,4,4,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,4,4,3,2,3,2,2,2,3,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,4,3,3,2,3,2,3,3,3,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,4,4,1,2,2,3,2,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,4,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
    {0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},
    {0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0}};
```

then I want to change the first couple (x and y) of integers:

```
tempMapMatrix[100][100] =
   {{5,5,5,5,5,1,2,3},
    {5,5,5,5,5,1,2,3},
    {5,5,1,1,1,1,2,3},
    {5,5,1,5,5,1,2,3},
    {5,5,1,1,1,1,2,3},
    {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
    {5,5,5,5,5,1,2,3},
    {5,2,2,2,5,1,2,3},
    {5,2,5,2,5,1,2,3},
    {5,2,2,2,5,1,2,3}};
```

but I'm getting an error (Expected Expression). I've tried

```
tempMapArray = stuff;
tempMapArray[][] = stuff;
```

but none work.

Any way to change the first couple of ints in the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over them, this is C, you don't have syntactic sugar to assingn pieces of arrays like you want. If you want to change, for example, every first element of each row you could do something like:

```
for (int = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
 tempMatrix[i][0] = 5;
}
```

so for the first couple of every row you should do

```
for (int = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
 tempMatrix[i][0] = 5;
 tempMatrix[i][1] = 5;
}
```

and so on.

Comment: So I guess I have to dealloc the matrix then make a new one. Is there any way I can dealloc the matrix then make a new one with the same name, or do I have to make a new one with a different name?

Comment: You don't have to dealloc/make a new one. You can just declare a new temp matrix with the changes you want and copy it over the part of the old matrix you want to change. `
 for (r=0; r<newRows; r++) {
  for (c=0; c<newCols; c++) {
  tempMatrix[r][c] = tempMatrix1[r][c];
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to access and change each element in the matrix individually.

I.e.:

```
tempMapMatrix[0][0] = 5;
tempMapMatrix[0][1] = //...
```

There is no way to "batch change" the contents of an array (one-dimensional or n-dimensional) in C.

The easiest way to achieve this effect is to write a for-loop and iterate over the contents of the two dimensional array and insert the required values in the required places.

Comment: So I guess I have to dealloc the matrix then make a new one. Is there any way I can dealloc the matrix then make a new one with the same name, or do I have to make a new one with a different name?

Comment: @aeubanks You don't have to `free()` the matrix at all if you don't want to. If you create the matrix using `malloc()`, you now own the heap space so you are free to modify the values inside it as you wish. Even if you create the array on the stack, as you have in your sample code, you still have access to all the memory space, so you may edit the values directly.

Comment: But can I edit them en mass? Because if not, that would be way too much trouble, so I would prefer dealloc then making a new one.

Comment: @aeubanks Ah fair enough, in that case yes, if it's neater to free the matrix and then create a new one that's fine. There isn't any way to edit them en mass once the array has been allocated.